# deserialize the json inside a json in arduino

Tags: json, arduino

My arduino is receiving via TCP a json that looks like this:

```
{"Order":9,"SenderID":"Master","Params":{"newSolution":"35"}}
```

I parse it doing using `#include <ArduinoJson.h>` like this:

```
void Connectivity::ProcessNewMessage(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length)
{
    StaticJsonDocument<80> doc;
    DeserializationError err = deserializeJson(doc, payload);
    if (err) {
        Serial.print(F("deserializeJson() failed with code "));
        Serial.println(err.c_str());
    }
    else
    {
        //we get the Order, or 99 if Order is not set. JsonDeserializer never makes exceptions
        //So the only way to know something was wrong is provide unexpected values as Order 99
        int Order = doc["Order"] | 99;
        switch(Order)
        {
            case 9:
            {
               //here I need to access the new solution that is 
               //in the Params.

                const char* serializedParams = (const char*) doc["Params"];
                Serial.println("testing 1:");
                Serial.println(serializedParams);
                Serial.println("++++1");
                DeserializationError err = deserializeJson(doc, serializedParams);
                if (err) {
                    Serial.print(F("deserializeJson() failed with code "));
                    Serial.println(err.c_str());
                }
                else
                {
                   //here the code when everything works
                }
             }
         }
```

This is the output I get when running the thing:

```
---
internal: Message arrived [master/Arduino] 
{"Order":9,"SenderID":"Master","Params":{"newSolution":"35"}}
testing 1:

++++1
deserializeJson() failed with code IncompleteInput`
```

As you can see the Params IS in the incoming json but when trying to access it, it is empty. Any ideas ?? Im an experienced C# coder but C++ and all the char char* const char mess is very old to me .. : )

Comment: Are you sure you need to call `deserializeJson` twice?

Comment: not sure.. but would make sense. This message is also parsed by other devices coded in micropython and there I needed to parse also the content. But my main problem is that serializedParams is empty

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the way I accessed the serializedParams. This solution is working:

```
//incoming string is : {"Order":9,"SenderID":"Master","Params":{"newSolution":"35"}}

    StaticJsonDocument<80> doc;
    DeserializationError err = deserializeJson(doc, payload);
    if (err) {
        Serial.print(F("deserializeJson() failed with code "));
        Serial.println(err.c_str());
    }
    else
    {
         const char* Params_newSolution = doc["Params"]["newSolution"];
         // Params_newsOlution contains = "35"
         float alreadyParsed = doc["Params"]["newSolution"];
         // alreadyParsed contains 35.0
    }
```